# Jupyter Notebook: Set JS variable from notebook cell

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to create a Jupyter notebook extension that requires me to pass a couple of variable values from Python to Javasciprt so that my JS extension can make use of said variables.
I am aware that we can create python variables from JS using
`IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("foo=11")`

However is the reverse possible?
Something like this? (this does not work)

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
Javascript('var foo = "bar"')
```

The worst case scenario is that I use get_selected_cell to read the contents of a cell and then parse that in my JS code. I am hoping to find a more elegant solution.